# Where do I connect a C-wire on my Honeywell TrueZone board?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

My [Honeywell TrueZone 311 board](https://customer.honeywell.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?cat=HonECC%20Catalog&pid=HZ311/U) does not have a terminal for the blue wire. Where does it go? I plugged in the wires for the dampers and the thermostats, but the five wires from the furnace to the zone board are incomplete due to the lack of a c terminal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [install instructions](https://forwardthinking.honeywell.com/related_links/zoning/truezone/install/69_2069efs.pdf), the zone board has dedicated R and C power terminals which should be connected to the corresponding transformer wires from the furnace, or to a dedicated 24VAC transformer if the furnace's transformer is not being used.  If your furnace doesn't provide a C wire (typically blue), update your post with pictures of the setup and we can provide more help.

Comment: for the equipment section of the zone board, I would only be using the yellow, white, green wires?

Comment: @user60061 -- R, W, Y, and G -- the R wire can be connected to the same incoming wire as the board-power R terminal is.

Answer (score 0):

The blue wire is typically the C or common. The thermostat and zone board does not need one to operate, but without it the thermostat will run on battery power.